# How do I add a record or carriage returned based upon the sub-string value

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Using SQL Server 2018, how can I create a sub-string and move it to the next line of the same record? See screenshot. I prefer to solve in the query rather than with a SSRS tool.

I get it basically working in Sql-Server Management Studio and then copy it to SQL Server Reporting Services and create further groupings  see screenshot.

[image: report query results]

I expect to see something similar to the screenshot except with the sub-string per time type on a separate line with corresponding "Billable-hours-Amount"

[image: SSRS Code Editor]

Comment: There is **no** SQL Server **2018** version - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and (soonish) 2019 - so which one are you really talking about??

Comment: Nope - not going to attempt to read your code from an image.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Please do not post images of your code. Add more details of the issue that you are facing.Share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Comment: The essence of what I am looking for is how to move a substring of "POLineNo" to the next line, carriage return with substring LineNoST or LineNoOT on the next line with the corresponding "BillableHoursOTHR"

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert a char(10) as well as char(13) something like.

```
DECLARE @cr char(2) = char(13) + char(10)

SELECT replace(mycolumn, 'LineNo', @cr + 'LineNo') FROM myTable
```